# How to avoid entering 'systemctl restart networkmanager' in order to activate wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless

Don't know what happened but whenever I turn my computer on, in order for my wifi to work I need to enter the following command and then the wifi icon appears and my wifi gets connected:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

As you understand I don't want to do this every single time, anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Is the service enabled? Before calling the `restart` check the `status`. You could try `systemctl enable network-manager` if the status shows as  not enabled. If it is enabled it will start on every system boot.

Comment: @StephenBoston I will check and let you know, what if it is not enabled (which is what I am guessing since it doesn't start on every system boot)?